# Find the differed value from two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays which might contain an array of objects or only array values.

just like below.

**array values structure.**

```
a = [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'} ]
```

or

```
a = ["abc" , "pqr"]
```

or

```
a = ["xyz"]
```

another array structure would be the same as the first one.

*How can I get the differed value from both the array.*

```
array1 = [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'}  , {value : 'abc' , label :'abc'} ]
array2 = [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'}]
```

> Note : I can't use any library.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Here is your answer, https://codeburst.io/comparison-of-two-arrays-using-javascript-3251d03877fe

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop or any [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods) methods? Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: yes. i tried using foreach loop. but it didn't worked for me as i might have different structure of an array as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question. Otherwise, it will be assumed that you are asking for us to do the coding for free. Hence the downvotes and close votes

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same structure of the objects or values, you could take a `Set` and stringified values (because of the object's different ) and filter the array for same stringified values.

```js
function getDifference(a, b) {
    var setB = new Set(b.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)));
    return a.filter(o => !setB.has(JSON.stringify(o)));
}

console.log(getDifference(["abc" , "pqr"], ["pqr"]));
console.log(getDifference(
   [{ value: 'xyz', label: 'xyz' }, { value: 'pqr', label: 'pqr' } , { value: 'abc', label:'abc' }],
   [{ value: 'xyz', label: 'xyz' }, { value: 'pqr', label: 'pqr' }]
));
```

For getting a symetrically difference, you need to call the function again with switched arrays.

```js
function getSymDifference(a, b) {
    return getDifference(a, b).concat(getDifference(b, a));
}

function getDifference(a, b) {
    var setB = new Set(b.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)));
    return a.filter(o => !setB.has(JSON.stringify(o)));
}

console.log(getSymDifference(["abc" , "pqr"], ["pqr", "xyz"]));
console.log(getSymDifference(
   [{ value: 'xyz', label: 'xyz' }, { value: 'pqr', label: 'pqr' } , { value: 'abc', label:'abc' }],
   [{ value: 'xyz', label: 'xyz' }, { value: 'pqr', label: 'pqr' }, { value: '111', label: '222' }]
));
```

Comment: i don't have same structure. i might have array of objects or only array values..

Comment: I think one of the arrays could be `["abc" , "pqr"]` as well

Comment: if one array has ["abc" , "pqr"] then another array would be ["xyz" , "abc"]. both the array structure would be same. but there might be an array of objects or there might be like  ["abc" , "pqr"].

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`:

```js
const array1 = [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'}  , {value : 'abc' , label :'abc'}];
const array2 = [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'}];
const res = array1.filter(e => array2.find(f => JSON.stringify(f) != JSON.stringify(e)));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all the unique values. You could check if the item is an `object`. If yes, get the label property, else use the item itself:

```js
function getMerged(array1, array2) {
  // get unique values from both array
  const set = new Set(array1.map(a => typeof a === 'object' ? a.label : a));
  array2.forEach(a => set.add(typeof a === 'object' ? a.label : a));
  
  // create an array of objects from the unique values
  return [...set].map(value => ({ label: value, value }))
}

console.log(getMerged(["abc" , "pqr"], [{value : 'xyz' , label : 'xyz'} , {value : 'pqr' , label :'pqr'} ]))
```